# Using ADO.net Entity Framework 4 with Enumerations? How do I do it?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, enums, poco, entity-framework-4

Question 1: I am playing around with EF4 and I have a model class like :

```
public class Candidate {

public int Id {get;set;}
public string FullName {get;set;}
public Gender Sex {get;set;}
public EducationLevel HighestDegreeType {get;set;}
}
```

Here Gender and EducationLevel are Enums like:

```
public enum Gender {Male,Female,Undisclosed}
public enum EducationLevel {HighSchool,Bachelors,Masters,Doctorate}
```

How do I get the Candidate Class and Gender and EducationLevel working with EF4 if:

- I do model first development
- I do db first development

Edit: Moved question related to object context to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065796/objectcontext-never-derives-from-an-interface-do-do-you-apply-di-ioc-in-case-of).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently `int <-> enum` [won't be supported in the initial release of EF](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adonetefx/thread/7659feab-d348-4367-b2cd-0456b20262fe)4.  I agree with those who say this sucks.

I am using a property that does the casting for me

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
  public MyEnum HurrEnum {get{return (MyEnum)Hurr;} set{Hurr = (int)value;}}
}
```

It doesn't look so bad if you name stuff "correctly" (which means, so it doesn't look stupid).  For instance, I have a ReasonCode enum that's stored as a Reason in the database, so I have Reason and ReasonCode versions of the property.  Works out well enough, for now.

---

*First, I'm just starting to use EF4 so I'm not intimate with how it works.  I assume its similar to L2S but with better entity support.  Take this with a grain of salt.*

To be clear, this property is for convenience and I'm 90% sure EF will react badly if you try to query the database using this property.  EF doesn't know about your property and cannot use it to construct sql.  So this:

```
var foo = from x in Db.Foos where x.HurrEnum == Hurr.Durr select x;
```

will probably fail to behave as expected where this:

```
var foo = Db.Foos.Where(x=> x.HurrEnum == Hurr.Durr);
```

probably will result in the entire Foos table being brought into memory and then parsed.  **This property is for convenience and should be used only after the database has been hit!**  Such as:

```
 // this is executed in the sql server
 var foo = Db.Foos.Where(x=> x.Hurr == 1 || x.Hurr == 2).ToArray();
 // this is then done in memory
 var hurrFoos = foo.Where(x=> x.HurrEnum == Hurr.Durr);
```

If you don't understand the difference is here then you're playing with fire.  You need to learn how EF/L2S interprets your code and converts it into sql statements.

Comment: BTW, the link is to an msdn forum question that's answered by Daniel Simmons who is dev lead on EF4.

Comment: Does this allow you to use this in a query? `.Where(x => x.HurrEnum = MyEnum.Foo);`?

Comment: Sure, you can do that.  However, that query won't (90% sure) be converted into sql.  My hack is for convenience only.  If you want the where clause to make it into sql you'll have to use the int.  Otherwise, it may throw or the where clause will be executed in memory rather than in sql.

Comment: Thanks for that, from what I know of EF is that it'll always throw, I haven't seen it executing part of a query in memory because it couldn't be mapped to SQL

Comment: This sucks! I hope it makes it in the .net 4 release. It doesnt make sense to say "we support POCO" without being able to use Enums, even tuples should work out of the box in some cases as part of your POCO. LAME!

Comment: Yeah, it is kinda lame.  It won't make it, however.  Look for it in 4.0 SP1 at the earliest.  The development team has gone into some detail about the issues with enums.  It seems easy enough, but apparently it isn't and they had to cut it to make the release date.  Oh well, so it goes sometimes...

Comment: Any workaround creating a linq expression / vistor to bypass this huge limit?

Comment: @Shimmy: Not that I've seen.  I've kind of soured on the magical ORM.  You can't really trust important work to code generators outside of your control.

Comment: @Will, The real problem is that you make your users (i.e. myself) developing those generators yourself, which is way more risky :)

Comment: @Shimmy: Been evaluating ORMs for a project coming up... I was thinking to myself, "Self, what would a [complex application, which must have high availability and be very fast despite an impressive workload,](http://stackoverflow.com) use as its ORM?  Because [that's an ORM that I should look into.](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)"