# Cast enum to integer

Tags: c#, .net, casting, enums

I have an enum class called `Gender`, and I have values in this like:

```
public enum GENDER
{
    MALE = 1,
    FEMALE = 2,
    OTHERS = 3,
}
```

And in my business object I just created a property for this, like:

```
public GENDER Gender
{
  get
  { 
      return gender; 
  }
  set 
  {
      gender = value; 
  }
}
```

In my database it's in type `integer`. For this I tried to assign the `Gender` value in the add function by its name `Gender`. But it's showing an error. Is it possible to cast the enum to integer so that it'll get the value automatically.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How are you writing to the database? If Entity Framework, then that doesn't support an enum/int conversion unfortunately. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2065612/121309).

Comment: am passing thru entity framework

Comment: @Dommer: In English, some things are neither male or female they are `neutral`. For instance a car is assigned the pronoun 'it'. Very unlike French where everything must be masculine or feminine. So there! Fundamentals of English Language for Programmers!

Comment: @Alex: Yes you're quite correct. Indeed in English things that can't be described as fauna are generally not assigned gender, although colloquially pretty much everything is assigned a gender at some point ;-p

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I cast int to enum in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/how-do-i-cast-int-to-enum-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (int)Gender is not enough to fix your cast issue, try to add int.Parse(var, int) in your code. It might be helpful...

Answer (score 5):

`(int)Gender` will do it. To cast a specific value instead of the property, you'll do something like `(int)GENDER.MALE`;

Answer (score 3):

Enums by default "inherit" from `int` (they are stored in `int` by default unless you choose another integral type), so you can simply cast to and from `int` without any trouble:

```
int i = (int)GENDER.MALE;

GENDER g = (GENDER)2;
```

Note that implicit casting is *not* supported. Casting must be explicit.

Beware that the cast doesn't do any checks of the range, so you can cast an `int` that doesn't have a `GENDER` value into a `GENDER` variable without error:

```
GENDER g = (GENDER)26;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a cast to convert between an integer and an enum value.

`int n = (int)GENDER.MALE;`

`GENDER g = (GENDER)1;`

If you're dealing with a string that you are reading from a database column (or any string for that matter) you can do the following:

`GENDER g = (GENDER) Enum.Parse(typeof(GENDER), "MALE");`

Note that Enum.Parse returns an object, so you have to cast it to your enum type first.

Comment: if i create a string property like, public string Name, I can simply give `Name` to pass the value right, in the same way is it possible to pass the enum value, coz am not sure the value is 1 or something else(in ur example its 1)

Comment: If you're dealing with strings, you have to go about it another way. I'll look it up and edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the database value to gender property, do this:

```
yourintdatabasefiled = (int)GENDER.yourproperty
```

Answer (score 1):

The following examples should suffice:

```
int val = (int)Gender.Male;
int val2 = (int)_gender;
```

There are also `System.Enum` methods to help you discover and manipulate enum values like:

```
Console.WriteLine("The values of the Gender Enum are: ");
foreach (int i in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers is right on it. Gender is now a type, just like int, so you can cast accordingly - both ways, too:

```
(int)Gender = . . .
/* Or */
(Gender)int = . . .
```

so, for

```
int i = (int)GENDER.male;
```

`i` would equal 1.

And the same for

```
Gender = GENDER.male;
i = (int)Gender;
```

`i` would also be 1.

Comment: You should example the reason `i = (int)Gender;` return 1.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Shanish, in your code you said 'public enum GENDER {male = 1, ...};' so if you set your Gender variable to GENDER.male like I did in the example, then when you (int) cast Gender you will get a value of 1 because that is the int equivalent that you assigned to male when you first made the enum. If you need more just ask!